# Add notes & footnotes to table

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report where I need to add a note/number where a record has data in a particular column.  I then need to add a reference to that to the bottom of the table, much like a footnotes section you would see in a book.

I've tried adding the rownumber but it pulls in the actual rownumber and not the record count.  I'm using oracle for my db.

In my report, if the record has a value for the column RETURN_NOTE (not shown), then concatenate an int tot he end of the TASK_NAME column.  Then underneath the table, add the int from above with the RETURN_NOTE value.

You can see the red numbers and their description in the image below.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go here is when you add a calculated field to your dataset where you put your footnotes into the expression. Lets assume your footnotes depend on the `Fields!Task.Value` and lets call this calculated field **Footnotes**:

```
'Name: Footnotes
=Switch(Fields!Task.Value = "Prepare for Coordinator", 1, Fields!Task.Value = "Ready for Closeout", 2)
```

Now add another column to your tablix and put the field `Fields!Footnotes.Value` in this column.

Then add a rectangle or another tablix somewhere in your report (put in the values which explains the footnotes). Then go to the properties of this tablix/rectangle (pane on the right) and under **Other > Bookmark** write in a bookmark code (for example: `FootnotesExplained`).

Go back to your textbox with the `Fields!Footnotes.Value` in it and right click on this textbox and go to **Text Box Properties > Action** and check the **Go to bookmark** option and write below your bookmark code from before `FootnotesExplained`.

When you click now on one of the value in the column where the footnotes are the report will jump to the tablix/rectangle where your footnotes descriptions are.